# Symfony2 Asset GreaterThan didn't work

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, doctrine

I have an issue actually.
The property "Quantity" in Invetory entity should not be negative.

So I try to use the GreaterThan or GreaterThanOrEqual assert in my entity declaration.

In fact, I can validate negative quantities. 
I don't understand.

The Entity :

```
/* src/Clicproxy/***Bundle/Entity/Inventory.php */
<?php

namespace Clicproxy\***Bundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 * Inventory
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Clicproxy\***Bundle\Entity\InventoryRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="audit, name", message="entity.inventory.unique")
 */
class Inventory
{
    /* [...] */

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="quantity", type="integer", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\GreaterThan(value = 1)
     */
    private $quantity;

[...]
```

The FormType :

```
/* src/Clicproxy/***Bundle/Form/InventoryCollabType.php */
<?php

namespace Clicproxy\***Bundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class InventoryCollabType extends AbstractType
{
        /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('quantity', null, array('label' => 'entity.inventory.quantity'))
            ->add('pageCostBlack', null, array('label' => 'entity.inventory.pagecostblack'))
            ->add('pageCostColor', null, array('label' => 'entity.inventory.pagecostcolor'))
            ->add('avMonthPagesBlack', null, array('label' => 'entity.inventory.avmonthpagesblack'))
            ->add('avMonthPagesColor', null, array('label' => 'entity.inventory.avmonthpagescolor'))
        ;
    }

    /* [...] */
}
```

The Controller :

```
public function configAction (Request $request, $slug)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $audit = $em->getRepository('Clicproxy***Bundle:Audit')->findOneBy(array('slug' => $slug));

    if (!$audit instanceof Audit) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('wizard.config.notfound');
    }

    $audit->addInventoriesFromEquipments($em->getRepository('Clicproxy***Bundle:Equipment')->findBy(array(), array('optimized' => 'ASC', 'name'=> 'ASC')));

    $form = $this->createCreateConfigForm($audit);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($audit);
        foreach ($audit->getInventories() as $inventory) {
            $inventory->setAudit($audit);
            $em->persist($inventory);
        }
        $em->flush();

        /* [...] */

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('wizard_result', array('slug' => $audit->getSlug())));
    }

    /* [...] */

    return array(
        'audit' => $audit,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
        'tabactive' => 2,
    );
}
```

Does anyone have an idea about my context ?

Thanks for your support,
David.

EDIT : 
Finaly I've write this code below, your opinion ?

```
public function configAction (Request $request, $slug)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $audit = $em->getRepository('Clicproxy***Bundle:Audit')->findOneBy(array('slug' => $slug));

    if (!$audit instanceof Audit) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('wizard.config.notfound');
    }

    $audit->addInventoriesFromEquipments($em->getRepository('Clicproxy***Bundle:Equipment')->findBy(array(), array('optimized' => 'ASC', 'name'=> 'ASC')));

    $form = $this->createCreateConfigForm($audit);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $validator = $this->get('validator');
        $errors_messages = array();
        foreach ($audit->getInventories() as $inventory)
        {
            $violations = $validator->validate($inventory);
            if (0 < $violations->count()) 
            {
                $error_message = substr($violations, strpos($violations, ':')+2);
                if (! in_array($error_message, $errors_messages, true)) {
                    $errors_messages[] = $error_message;
                    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('error', $error_message);
                }

            }
        }
        if (! $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->has('error'))
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($audit);
            foreach ($audit->getInventories() as $inventory) {
                $inventory->setAudit($audit);
                $em->persist($inventory);
            }
            $em->flush();

            /* [...] */

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('wizard_result', array('slug' => $audit->getSlug())));
        }
    }


    return array(
        'audit' => $audit,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
        'tabactive' => 2,
    );
}
```

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Can you show the logic you use to handle the form submission?

Comment: I've just add the logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't validating your entity, just your form.

It's a common mistake to assume that when you call `$form->isValid()` that your Doctrine entity is being validated, but that's not the case.

You need to explicitly call the validator service and handle that separately from the validation of your form.

That would looks something like this:

```
$validator = $this->get('validator');
$errors = $validator->validate($inventory);

if (count($errors) > 0) {
    // Handle errors here
}
```

For more information, take a look at the [validation documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#using-the-validator-service).

Comment: I just add the code I've just write, can you give me your opinion ?

Comment: You should be returning an error inside your if statement where you check if there are violations. That and `0 < $violations->count()` is really awkward. It's much more readable to write `$violations->count() > 0`. Other than that, it looks good

Comment: I've added `$form->get('XXX')->addError(new FormError('Message'));` to handle the error information in the template.